# FloatingActionButton does not come down when dismissing Snackbar

Tags: android, dismiss, floating-action-button, snackbar

I am trying to use a `Snackbar`. I have a `FloatingActionButton` wrapped in a `CoordinatorLayout`. When the `Snackbar` shows, the button is correctly moved up. When it dismisses automatically, the button moves down. But if I dismiss the `Snackbar` programmatically, the button does not go down. My code is simple:

```
mSnackbar = Snackbar.make(mCoordinatorLayout, text, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction(R.string.undo, new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        undoDeleteTasks();
                    }
                });
        mSnackbar.show();
```

Is there a way to make the `FloatingActionButton` move down when the `Snackbar` is dismissed programmatically?

Comment: Don't use coordinate layout as your view.  Use the FloatingActionButton.  Snackbar.make(mFab, text, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)

Comment: @EugeneH I have tried it, but there is no difference. The fab still keeps up when the snackbar is dismissed using mSnackbar.dismiss();

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
Snackbar mysnack = Snackbar.make( fab, "Hi, welcome to my app!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG );
mysnack.getView().addOnAttachStateChangeListener( new View.OnAttachStateChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onViewAttachedToWindow( View v ) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewDetachedFromWindow( View v ) {
        fab.setTranslationY( 0 );
    }
});
mysnack.show();
```

Comment: It works! Thanks @Farzad119. Just one detail. View.OnAttachStateChangeListener was added in API Level 12. What could I use in API Level 11 or lower?

Answer (score 13):

The problem is, in an `CoordinatorLayout`, the FAB is moved because its behavior class's `onDependentViewChanged()` is called when the `Snackbar` animates in or out.

However, when you call `Snabackbar.dismiss()` no animation takes place. And therefore no `onDependentViewChanged()`. And thus movement of the FAB.

I want to know if it possible to either

1. animate the Snackbar dismiss?
2. create a behavior that moves the FAB when the Snackbar causes onDependentViewRemoved()?

Farzad119's answer is arguably a little brittle. My approach--although not satisfactory either--is to alter the behavior on the FAB to move the FAB down when the `SnackBar` is removed:

```
   @Override
   public void onDependentViewRemoved(CoordinatorLayout parent, FloatingActionButton child, View dependency) {
     super.onDependentViewRemoved(parent, child, dependency);
     float translationY = Math.min(0, parent.getBottom() - child.getBottom());
     child.setTranslationY(translationY);
   }
```

Comment: That works for me, but i think you can just set translation Y to 0 if dependency is snackbar.snackbarLayout

Comment: Great, thanks! The explanation seems correct, although your code didn't work for me. but as @Cheng mentions, settings translation Y to 0 works.

Answer (score 3):

To solve this issue I defined a RelativeLayout Behavior like this. This can be done for any view, just replace all RelativeLayout with desired UI element.

```
public class RelativeLayoutBehavior extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<RelativeLayout> {

    public RelativeLayoutBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, RelativeLayout child, View dependency) {
        return dependency instanceof Snackbar.SnackbarLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, RelativeLayout child, final View dependency) {
        Float translationY = Math.min(0, dependency.getTranslationY() - dependency.getHeight());
        child.setTranslationY(translationY);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDependentViewRemoved(CoordinatorLayout parent, RelativeLayout child, View dependency) {
        child.setTranslationY(0);
    }
}
```

Then you need to add the Behavior into the RelativeLayout "android:layout_behavior" property like this. Make sure the RelativeLayout you want to slide up is inside of a CoordinateLayout also.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_coordinate_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#323232"
    tools:context="com.choch.michaeldicioccio.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_relative_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        app:layout_behavior="com.yourPackagePath.RelativeLayoutBehavior" >

        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:clickable="true"
            app:elevation="8dp"
            app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_navigation_color_selector"
            app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_navigation_color_selector"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_bar_menu" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/add_car_fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_above="@id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_plus_black_36dp"
            android:tint="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:elevation="8dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```