# Animate Snackbar's dismiss() to move the FAB

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-snackbar, floating-action-button

In an `CoordinatorLayout`, a FAB is moved because its behavior class's `onDependentViewChanged()` is called when the `Snackbar` animates in or out.

However, when you call `Snabackbar.dismiss()` no animation takes place. And therefore no `onDependentViewChanged()`. And thus movement of the FAB.

Is it possible to either

1. animate the `Snackbar` dismiss?
2. create a behavior that moves the FAB when the `Snackbar` causes `onDependentViewRemoved()`?

This is arguably a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32798807). Yet it doesn't suggest any solutions to create the dismiss animation--but the solutions there may provide a practical solution in the meantime.

Comment: The 'best' solution I've come up with so far, is to make the FAB translate to the `CoordinatorLayout`'s bottom in `onDependentViewRemoved()`--although obviously if your FAB needs to be elsewhere this would have to change--once the `Snackbar` is removed: `float translationY = Math.min(0, coord.getBottom() - fab.getBottom()); fab.setTranslationY(translationY);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FloatingActionButton does not come down when dismissing Snackbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32798807/floatingactionbutton-does-not-come-down-when-dismissing-snackbar)

Comment: Yes, I'll merge it in. Although the solution is the same as the comment above, practically.